# insert comma into string in php

Tags: php, string

how do i insert a comma in string like

```
$str = "0470   06102009                                2981485GIR ADE TAUHID";
```

every length i put in array like

```
$legth = array(7,8,15,50);
```

i just wanna make the result like

```
0470  ,06102009 ,2981485GIR     ,ADE TAUHID
```

where every string splited according to length on the array, including whitespace,

```
length(7),length(8),length(15),length(50)
```

how i do that ?

Comment: 1) if permitted strip subsequent spaces and then replace space with ,

Comment: With a length of 15 for the third field you would get a string with only spaces and that doesn't match your expected outcome.

Comment: length(15) including whitespace, look at the fisrt string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$offset = 0;
$result = implode(",",array_map(function($length) use ($str,&$offset) {
    $part = substr($str,$offset,$length);
    $offset += $length;
    return $part;
},$legth));
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/ISWZuO

Please note that the output of the demo is what you "should" get based on the input you provided. Your input is wrong for the output you say you want - adjust `$legth` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
$oldString = "0470   06102009                                2981485GIR ADE TAUHID";
$newstring = implode(", ", preg_split("/[\s]+/", $oldString));
echo $newstring;
```

**EDIT**:

If you need output on the basis of your array. Then I think you need to modify your array first. And apply below code:

```
$legth = array(7,8,15,50);
$str = "0470   06102009                                2981485GIR ADE TAUHID";

$first = 0;
foreach($legth as $l){
   echo substr($str , $first, $l)."<br />";
   $first = $first + $l;
}
```

Comment: It would put `"ADE"` and `"TAUHID"` in separate strings.

Comment: @Ja͢ck : yes. you are right. I am trying to modify this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure of the number of spaces and you want to keep them, you can use `substr`

```
// substr( your string, start, length )
substr($str , 0, 7)
```